# Understanding select() in socket programming

Tags: sockets, unix, select

I am in a gaming scenario. Both the server and clients exchange messages through non-blocking UDP in a high rate.

(Maybe odd here...) The legacy code also uses `select()` with timeout value set to `0`, which means `select()` does not block. `select()` is within a forever while loop. Upon `select()` returns a number greater than `0`, following code goes receive message through `recvfrom()`. If it returns `0`, following code does not try receiving.

From print-out info, I saw `select()` sometimes returns `1` (greater than `0`). I am confused that since timeout is set to `0`, how does `select()` have time to check if a message is ready to read from any of `readfds`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html):

> Upon successful completion, the pselect() or select() function shall
>   modify the objects pointed to by the readfds, writefds, and errorfds
>   arguments to indicate which file descriptors are ready for reading,
>   ready for writing, or have an error condition pending, respectively,
>   and shall return the total number of ready descriptors in all the
>   output sets. For each file descriptor less than nfds, the
>   corresponding bit shall be set upon successful completion if it was
>   set on input and the associated condition is true for that file
>   descriptor.
>
> **If none of the selected descriptors are ready for the requested operation, the pselect() or select() function shall block until at least one of the requested operations becomes ready, until the timeout occurs, or until interrupted by a signal.** The timeout parameter controls how long the pselect() or select() function shall take before timing out. If the timeout parameter is not a null pointer, it specifies a maximum interval to wait for the selection to complete. If the specified time interval expires without any requested operation becoming ready, the function shall return. If the timeout parameter is a null pointer, then the call to pselect() or select() shall block indefinitely until at least one descriptor meets the specified criteria. **To effect a poll, the timeout parameter should not be a null pointer, and should point to a zero-valued timespec structure.**

In short, checking the descriptors happens before checking the timeout. If the socket already has data ready when `select()` is called, the timeout is ignored and `select()` exits immediately.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also explain why they use both select() and non-blocking for the purpose of achieving immediate returns? If select() returns 0, the legacy code does not go and receive - immediate return after select(); otherwise (select() returns 1), that should mean there has already been some data ready for receiving, and hence safe to pick them up without any blocking time - immediate return after recvfrom(). Since either of two cases guarantees immediate returns, why bother setting the socket to non-blocking? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Historically (pre-Linux), `select` followed by `read` on a blocking socket would never block, and POSIX still requires this. But Linux deliberately violates POSIX because the Linux developers say the POSIX requirement is "impossible to implement", even though BSD does implement it and has done so since the mid-1980s. See https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/6/18/76 and follow-ups for details.